# Picking two groups of students from a class.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Today in class we were given a extra-credit quiz, and this was the question:

> In a class of 40 students, 4 students receive a 4.0 and 2 students receive a 3.0 at random. All other students receive a 2.0. How many different grade combinations are there?

My immediate thought was that we choose 4 students from the 40, then choose 2 students from the remaining 36 ie ${40 \choose 4} \times {36 \choose 2}$. However, I feel as though I may be missing something. Is my reasoning correct, or am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your work looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.  Alternatively, you can write four $4$s, two $3$s and thirty four $2$s in a row, then assign them to the students in alphabetical order.  The number of possible rows is
$$\frac{40!}{4!\,2!\,34!}\ ,$$
and you can confirm that this is the same as your answer.